# Compiler error installing python-igraph: Warnings treated as errors

Tags: python, gcc, python-3.x, igraph, gcc-warning

Trying to install `python-igraph` with pip for Python 3, I get the following compiler error. Can I change something or is this a bug in igraph? Note the line `cc1: some warnings being treated as errors` in the end - if they are just warnings, can I just ignore them somehow?

```
Extracting igraph-0.7.0.tar.gz...

Configuring igraph...

Build type: static extension

Include path: igraphcore/include

Library path: igraphcore/lib /usr/local/lib64 /usr/local/lib /usr/lib64 /usr/lib /lib64 /lib

Linked dynamic libraries: xml2 z m stdc++

Linked static libraries: igraphcore/lib/libigraph.a

Extra compiler options:

Extra linker options:

building 'igraph._igraph' extension

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4

creating build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -Iigraphcore/include -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/edgeobject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/edgeobject.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -Iigraphcore/include -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/igraphmodule.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/igraphmodule.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -Iigraphcore/include -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/edgeseqobject.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/edgeseqobject.o

gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Werror=declaration-after-statement -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -Iigraphcore/include -I../../build/include -I../../include -I/usr/local/include/igraph -I/usr/include/igraph -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c src/filehandle.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/src/filehandle.o

src/filehandle.c: In function ‘igraphmodule_filehandle_init’:

src/filehandle.c:38:5: error: ISO C90 forbids mixed declarations and code [-Werror=declaration-after-statement]

cc1: some warnings being treated as errors

error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/export/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-o27hxbqk-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /export/tmp/pip_build_root/python-igraph
Storing debug log for failure in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has recently been patched in igraph; see the [corresponding issue](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/679) on Github.

Comment: How do I find and apply your patch? I have cloned the repository and ran `setup.py` but the error still appears.

Comment: You probably checked out the `master` branch, which is the latest released version. You need to switch to the `develop` branch first.