# pip install igraph for python 3.4: compiler error

Tags: python, c, macos, pip, igraph

I want to install [python-igraph](http://igraph.org/python/#pyreq) for Python 3.4 on Mac OSX 10.10.

When I do

```
jenny$ pip3 install python-igraph
```

I get

```
checking whether the C compiler works... no

configure: error: in `/private/var/folders/q7/jc5nc2px3p1_sr6gnj7749wc0000gq/T/pip_build_jenny/python-igraph/tmp/igraph.p_05kabc/igraph-0.7.1':

configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables

See `config.log' for more details



Extracting igraph-0.7.1.tar.gz...

Configuring igraph...

Could not download and compile the C core of igraph.



----------------------------------------
Cleaning up...
Command /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/python3.4 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/q7/jc5nc2px3p1_sr6gnj7749wc0000gq/T/pip_build_jenny/python-igraph/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/q7/jc5nc2px3p1_sr6gnj7749wc0000gq/T/pip-vudi0il0-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/q7/jc5nc2px3p1_sr6gnj7749wc0000gq/T/pip_build_jenny/python-igraph
```

I checked out [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26117722/compiler-error-installing-python-igraph-warnings-treated-as-errors), and the linked [githib issue](https://github.com/igraph/igraph/issues/679) and then tried

```
pip3 install python-igraph --install-option="--c-core-version=0.7.1"
```

based on the information I found, with essentially the same error.

Based on the comments in that stackoverflow question, I also tried looking for the developer branch of [python-igraph on github](https://github.com/igraph/python-igraph) but I can't find it.

I'm a little lost. Can anyone tell me how to install this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a c compiler installed?
How about Xcode Command Line Tools?

Try executing the following from your terminal:

```
xcode-select --install
```

And click the "Install" button on the pop-up window.

After it's installed, verify the Xcode Command Line Tools installation with:

```
gcc --version
```

Then try your pip3 installation again.

Comment: Yep. I had Xcode installed, but recently restored my system from a Time Machine backup and needed to accept the Xcode license again. I got a notification asking for acceptance of the license agreement when I did sudo gcc --version, so it was easy to figure out from there. Thanks!